# python script slow read and write gz files

Tags: python, gzip

I have a xxx.wig.gz file, that have 3,000,000,000 lines in such format:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=1 step=1
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
fixedStep chrom=chr2 start=1 step=1
0
0
0
0
0
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
...
```

and i want to

1. break it down by "chrom". So every time I read a line starts with "fixedstep", I create a new file and close old one.
2. I want 0/1 output by comparing each value to a "threshold", pass=1 otherwise 0

below is my python script which runs super slow (I am projecting it to finish ~10hours, so far 2 chromosomes done after ~1 hour)

can someone help me improve it?

```
#!/bin/env python    
import gzip    
import re    
import os    
import sys   

fn = sys.argv[1]    
f  = gzip.open(fn)    
fo_base = os.path.basename(fn).rstrip('.wig').rstrip('.wig.gz')    
fo_ext  = '.bt.gz'    
thres = 100    
fo = None    
for l in f:    
    if l.startswith("fixedStep"):    
        if fo is not None:    
            fo.flush()    
            fo.close()    
        fon  = re.search(r'chrom=(\w*)', l).group(0).split('=')[-1]    
        fo   = gzip.open(fo_base + "_" + fon + fo_ext,'wb')    
    else:    
        if int(l.strip())>= thres:    
            fo.write("1\n")    
        else:    
            fo.write("0\n")    
if fo is not None:    
    fo.flush()    
    fo.close()    
f.close()
```

PS. I assume awk can do it much faster but I am not great with awk

Comment: Can you give an example of how the output would look for the sample data provided?  It seems like that would be 2 files, perhaps called chr1 and chr2.  What would be the contents of chr1 and of chr2?  You're right about awk being able to do it pretty quickly, I suspect, but I'd like to make sure it passes your test data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Summer for editing the text.
I added buffered read/write to the script and now it is several times faster (still relatively slow though):

```
import io    
f  = io.BufferedReader( gzip.open(fn) )    
fo   = io.BufferedWriter( gzip.open(fo_base + "." + fon + fo_ext,'wb') )
```